# Set Default Value of Field in Table using current autoNumber MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Title says it all - is this possible? I was hoping to set it in properties and not go to code. IF its not possible I guess I can go to vba, but was hoping one of you cats has an answer.

This is what i tried so far but it doesnt like it

```
="RF"+[tblMasterRefundsIssues].[ID]
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but the question is why would you want to have a separate field in the table that doesn't hold any additional information? If the prefix is constant, then you can always display this in forms or reports by basing them on a query that adds it in for you.

Comment: Due to varying different data sets that get combined into a master accdb file I was trying to have unique keys that are distinguishable by project. I have decided to give up and add prefix when data gets moved form file to file. Easier to get the same result. I was just being lazy and didnt want to design an ETL

Comment: @Skippy turns out i was super lazy on my google-fu too http://www.databasedev.co.uk/add_prefix.html

Comment: You have been fooled. The Format just controls the display of the values, not the values themselves.

Comment: @Gustav Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooo!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Add a field to your table, say, *SourceId*, and set the default value of that to "RF" controlled by your project - or better, design it as a foreign key to hold your ProjectId and apply a compound unique index on *ProjectId* and *Id*.

Comment: Will try it in the AM and leave feedback accordingly

Comment: @Fionnuala: "Due to varying different data sets that get combined into a master accdb file ..."

Comment: This should be part of the question, not a throw-away comment (comments are not important and may be deleted on SO).